# Find the limit when $x\rightarrow\infty$ of $y=\ln x-1/x^2$

Tags: limits

Find the limit when $x\rightarrow\infty$ of $y=\ln x-1/x^2$ using the theorem:  if $g(x)>f(x)$ and $\lim\, f(x)=\infty$ then $\lim\, g(x)=\infty$ (when $x\rightarrow\infty$.)

Here's what I did:$$\ln x-(1/x^2)>\ln x-1 \quad (\text{for }x>1)$$
$$\ln x-1/x^2>\ln x-\ln e$$
$$\ln x-1/x^2>\ln(x/e)$$
$$\lim\, \ln(x/e)=\infty$$ so $$\lim\left(\ln x-1/x^2\right)=\infty$$
Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. The $\ln x-1=\ln(x/e)$ step is unnecessary as you can directly state that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\ln x-1=\infty$.